# Are the wilds safe (for beginners)?

Tags: discworld-mud, muds

I am a low level character still, and have spent all my time in Anhk-Morpork. I would like to leave the city and wander around the wilderness, but I'm not sure if I could survive.

(a) At what point can I start exploring the open world, or (b) are there regions in the open world that are designed for characters of specific levels?

Comment: If it's faithful to the books, it'll be safer than Anhk-Morpork.

Comment: @theJollySin I haven't MUDded in over a decade but when I did, there was an "area" or "areas" command (I think the former) which showed all areas and their associated suggested level(s).  That comes with stock ROM, I am not sure what codebase yours is on.  Due to my datedness and lack of codebase, I am commenting rather than answering.

Comment: @joedragons The Discworld MUD is (apparently) based on LPMud and the Fluffy OS. That doesn't mean a lot to me, but there you go. Thanks!